# Unable to sent message through WhatsApp Business API

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, graphql, whatsapp

I am trying to send WhatsApp message, using WhatsApp Business API and GraphQL.

But I am getting this error:

```
Failed to send message to : 
{
    "error":{
        "message":"(#132012) Parameter format does not match format in the created template",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":132012,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product":"whatsapp",
            "details":"header: Format mismatch, expected IMAGE, received UNKNOWN"
        },
        "fbtrace_id":"AyPLLsvyikPmg66DWF_ZfYU"
    }
}
```

This is the code I have written. And also I am sharing the message structure.

```
import requests
import openpyxl


access_token = ""
template_name = "healthy_sports_b2s_2"  # Replace with your template name
language_code = "en"


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("numbers.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active


for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    customer_number = row[0]
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/messages"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    message_payload = {
        "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
        "to": customer_number,
        "type": "template",
        "template": {"name": template_name, "language": {"code": language_code}},
        "components": [
            {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "type": "template",
                        "image": {
                            "link": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dapnrioqr/image/upload/v1691648851/02_wgucrp.jpg"
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }

    response = requests.post(url, json=message_payload, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f"Message sent to {customer_number}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to send message to {customer_number}: {response.text}")
```

What can I do to solve this

[This is the actual message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVppq.png)

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot of the message template is not enough, You need to show the template settings from the edit template, where you have added the parameters.

I can see the issue in your header component in the request, should provide the type of the component `header` and the type of the parameter `image`,

```
"components": [
  {
    "type": "header",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "type": "image",
        "image": {
          "link": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dapnrioqr/image/upload/v1691648851/02_wgucrp.jpg"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If the error still persists then you need to look into [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates).

Comment: Kindly see the template editing page, 
https://res.cloudinary.com/dapnrioqr/image/upload/v1691678557/Screenshot_from_2023-08-10_18-40-42_vcyhnt.png
https://res.cloudinary.com/dapnrioqr/image/upload/v1691678557/Screenshot_from_2023-08-10_18-40-30_ud7smp.png

Comment: Okay, the provided answer should work.